# Angular 5 Resolver no entrega los datos antes del load de la ventana

Tags: angular, angular5

Actualmente he desarrollado una interfaz de usuario simple para permitir que el usuario seleccione de una lista desplegable un valor para redireccionarlo a diferentes URL. El problema que se me presenta es que la llamada asíncrona siempre entrega los datos después de que ha terminado de cargarse el html del desplegable, por lo que aunque si se entregan los datos ala formulario, la lista nunca se llena con los datos recibidos.

Inicialmente empleaba una llamada al endpoint que de una api que entrega los datos empleando un servicio en angular y en las pruebas de mi portatil funcionaba correctamente, pero al realizar la busqueda hacia un servicio de BBDD en la nube (mLab específicamente) no encuentro la forma de que funcione.

Leyendo, he encontrado la solución de usar un resolver que permita traer primero los datos y luego cargar la pagina, la verdad no sé que hago mal pero todavía no funciona. Les dejo mi código a ver si hago algo mal y me pueden ayudar.

**docs-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { DocumentationService } from '../documentation.service';
import { Logger } from '../logger.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-docs-list',
    templateUrl: './docs-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./docs-list.component.css']
})
export class DocsListComponent implements OnInit {

  urlSelected = '';
  docsAvailable = [
    {name: 'Seleccione una opción ...', url: '', group: '', order: 0},
  ];
  groups = [];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private http: HttpClient,
              private documentationService: DocumentationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('EJECUTADO EL INIT DE LA PAGINA');

    this.docsAvailable = this.route.snapshot.data['docs'];
    console.log(this.docsAvailable);
  }

  onChange(value) {
    // console.log(value);
    this.urlSelected = value;
  }
}
```

** documentation-resolver.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
 import { DocumentationService } from './documentation.service';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 @Injectable()
 export class DocumentationResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private documentationService: DocumentationService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        console.log('EJECUTANDO EL OBSERVABLE ...');
        return this.documentationService.getDocs().map(user => {});
    }
}
```

** documentation.service.ts **

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Logger } from './logger.service';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DocumentationService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private logger: Logger) { }

  getDocs(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('IMPRESION DESDE EL SERVICIO ...');
    return this.http.get('documents');
  }

}
```

Gracias de antemano.

UPDATE: me falto una pieza importante el fichero:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DocsListComponent } from './docs-list/docs-list.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Logger } from './logger.service';
import { DocumentationService } from './documentation.service';
import { DocumentationResolver } from './documentation- 
    resolver.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
     component: DocsListComponent,
    resolve: {
       docs: DocumentationResolver
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
     DocsListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {enableTracing: true}
    )
  ],
   providers: [
     Logger,
     DocumentationService,
     DocumentationResolver
   ],
   bootstrap: [
     AppComponent
   ]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Allí se muestran las rutas y la definición del resolver como provider.

Comment: Creo que te estás complicando la vida demasiado: es normal que los servicios devuelvan un resultado de maner asíncrona, y que el componente se cargue sin datos *y luego* se refresque con los datos obtenidos. Posiblemente tenías un error distinto al que creías cuando empezaste a usar el *Resolver*

Comment: Pablo, gracias por tu respuesta. Lo de la comunicación asíncrona lo doy por sentado. Lo que me tiene descolocado es que no hay manera de que el componente se refresque con los datos obtenidos. Sé que en AngularJS se empleaba $scope.$apply, pero aquí en Angular 5/6 no sé como forzar el refrescamiento.

Comment: Se refresca *solo*: en cuanto los atributos tienen valores la plantilla se actualiza. Por eso digo que si no te funcionó a la primera, habría seguramente algún otro fallo.

Comment: Quizá lo que veo es que la latencia del servicio en la red está afectando la carga. Bueno de nuevo mucha gracias por tus opiniones. Si ves algo más no dudes en comentarme.

Comment: Puedes, si quieres, volver al código antes de usar el Resolver y rehacer la pregunta ;)